# linux, networking, setting up subnet

Tags: linux, networking, subnet

I have a group of servers (debian linux boxes) and each gets a public IP off eth0.  Lots of data is processed and passed between the servers.  I'd like to create a subnet between the servers off each servers eth1 and link them all to a separate switch just for passing data between the servers.

When the servers are networked to the secondary switch on eth1, do I just need to manually assign IPs (from 172.16.0.1+) to each server?  If so how exactly do I do this from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you want to edit /etc/network/interfaces and
make it look like this:

```
# dont change eth0 entry
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual (or maybe dhcp) 
#    
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 172.16.0.1
network 172.16.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 172.16.0.255
```

Afterwards, either /etc/init.d/networking restart  or reboot.

This is from looking at my Ubuntu config and adapting it for your needs.
Ubuntu and Debian are supposed to be similar.

Comment: You can use "ifup eth1" to start the eth1 interface.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to assign to all your servers an IP. You also could do Vlans tagging to only have to change your network configuration (without installing a new network card on the servers and plug into a new switch). Then you need to create 2 separated vlans on your switchs and all will works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just for testing purpose:

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.7.24 netmask 255.255.255.128 up
```

If it ist working, write it down in your `/etc/network/interfaces`